# MySQL connector 6.3.5 with .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

I am developing a project in Visual Studio 2010 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. I have been able to successfully connect to a local MySQL database without any issues.

However, if I try to change the target framework to .NET 3.5, I am having problems referencing the `MySql.Data` DLL. I can see it fine when the target framework is .NET 4.0.

Does anyone have any idea why I can't use it with .NET 3.5? Does it have to do with the version of the MySQL connector?

When I try to add a reference to `MySql.Data`, I get the following error:

> *'MySql.Data', or one of its dependencies, requires a later version of the .NET framework than the one specified in the project.*

I have the most recent version of the MySQL connector and it doesn't say anything about a specific version of the .NET framework.

Comment: I had a the same issue and ended up using MySql connector 5.1.7 which does work for .net 2.0 http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=367415

Answer (score 0):

You saw this bug report in relation to your problem? Although initially reported in 6.3.1, it says it got fixed in 6.3.3: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53686